# Enable form scrolling when mouse is over listbox in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

MS Access mouse wheel scrolling on a form behaves where the form itself will only scroll when the mouse cursor is over a form detail or other objects. However, when the mouse cursor is placed over-top of a listbox control, the entire form will not scroll. The listbox object itself will scroll.

I would like to know if there is any API code that behaves as such:

Mouse cursor is over top of listbox then wheel scroll entire form.
If listbox object is selected, then mouse wheel scrolls listbox content.

This is standard behavior. MS Access has poor default behavior here.

Are there any API resources to achieve this?

I desperately need this functionality! Thank you

Comment: I would use a combobox instead of listbox if listbox cannot be sized to always show all items. Unfortunately, even if listbox could be sized to display all items, it still interferes with form scroll. Darn!

Comment: June7:  So, are we concluding this is not possible? Certainly there must be some API code someone much more intelligent than myself has written.

Comment: Bing: Access VBA disable listbox scroll. Anything in here help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bfd2efc8-7ca5-4694-adc2-a202619e0680/disabling-the-vertical-scrollbar-from-a-listbox ?

Comment: June7:  I'm not entirely sure were are on the same page about what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I understand what you want. Code to disable listbox scroll was a long shot with hopes if it was disabled it would no longer interfere with form scroll. I am inclined to think what you want is not possible.

Comment: The APIs you need are 1. catching mouse wheel events. 2. Controling form scroll. Did you google for that?

Comment: Siyon DP, i have googled that. But that is not entirely true. I need 1. Catch mouse wheel events, 2) get cursor position relative to listbox item in form and 3) control the form scroll..... All of which I do not know where to begin. If i could even get items 1 and 2, I have no idea how I would scroll the access form.